# Customize Search WordPress Form

Tags: wordpress, forms, search, conditional-statements

.Hi guys

How do I execute the following code:

```
 If    ID search form == book 
   {The Post excluded from the search} 
else 
   {excluded a custom post type "book"}
```

my search form are:
the first

```
<form id="book" > it's a custom post type
```

The second

```
<form id="post" > //It's default Post type WordPress
```

Can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Place this code in your function.php file.

It will search the content from both post type book and post

```
function filter_search($query) {
if ($query->is_search) {
$query->set('post_type', array('post', 'book'));
};
return $query;
};
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'filter_search');
```

Comment: Thank you very much for reply.

But unfortunately it did not succeed. It seems I have not explained the idea
I have two forms of search:
First: I want to just look for the book, of course, have a special Theme.
And the other is to look at all the site without the book.
As shown in the image below.

Comment: <img src="http://i.stack.imgur.com/KuC5f.jpg" width="800" height="600">